# What does THEN in this CASE statement does?

Tags: sql, sqlite

folks!

Could someone please explain to me this `CASE` statement? I'm puzzled about the `THEN user_id`, what does it does exactly?

```
SELECT modal_text,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
    WHEN ab_group = 'control' THEN user_id
    END) AS 'control_clicks'
FROM onboarding_modals
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It yields `user_id` if and only if `ab_group = 'control'`. In any other case it yields `NULL` the implicit default.

Comment: I would try it out on an actual database.  But I believe it means `the count of all unique "user_id" whose ab_group = 'control'`.  The count *excludes* a) rows where ab_group <> "control", and b) multiple rows with the same user_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple aggregation:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
```

and it counts all the distinct non null `user_id`s.
 
But this is *conditional aggregation*:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ab_group = 'control' THEN user_id END)
```

and it counts the distinct non null `user_id`s only if in the same row the column `ab_group` contains the value `'control'`.

Answer (score 1):

For an AB test , the select statement is trying to find out the the count of distinct users in control_group.

So instead of counting all distinct users for each modal_text, the case is counting the user only if it is in control_group i.e. the column ab_group = 'control'

Answer (score 0):

THEN is a conditional statement.

To explain you more clearly,

**If your ab_group column has value 'control' then print user_id column**

It's similar to if else statement

```
if (ab_group = 'control')
{
user_id
}
```

Use below link to understand more,

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp